# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode, preg-replace-callback

I am new to Mysqli_* and I am getting these errors:

(PHP 4 >= 4.0.5, PHP 5, PHP 7)

preg_replace_callback — Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback

```
$url = preg_replace('/\/index.php$/i', '', reset($url = explode('?', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])));
```

I've read the PHP site and I am just not seeing something. I've tried using preg_replace_callback and splitting the striing and still not working.

Comment: What does this have to do with `mysqli_*`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `preg_replace_callback`? That's needed if you need to calculate the replacement dynamically, not if you just want to replace with an empty string.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The only argument that has to be passed by reference to `preg_replace()` is the optional 5th argument, a variable that receives the count of replacements that were made. You shouldn't get this error when only passing 3 arguments.

Comment: the error is: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference . not Mysqli typed the wrong heading - sorry

Comment: The problem is with the argument to `reset()`. It needs to be a variable, not a variable assignment.

Comment: Put the assignment on the previous line.

Comment: You _actually_ should just do... `$url = preg_replace('/(?:\/index\.php)?\??.*$/i', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` This will remove `/index.php`(if it exists) and anything after the first question mark.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the call to `reset()`, just put the call to `explode()` there.

```
$url = preg_replace('/\/index\.php$/i', '', explode('?', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
```

Comment: Please escape the dot for educational purposes.  I think the OP wants to target the url before the querystring `[0]`.